# If metabox value = display or echo else

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, metadata, custom-post-type

I was wondering if someone could help out? I have a custom post type with custom meta boxes, I would like to have an if and else statement that displays an image or echo text with a class if one of  the meta box values is =  no. else the meta box stays the same.

Thanks !!!

Comment: <?php

$available=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'available_drop_down', true );

<?php if ($available=='no') {

echo "<li> UNAVAILABLE </li>";

}else { ?>
 do nothing
<?php } ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php $available=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'available_drop_down', true );
      if ($available == 'no') {
         echo "<li> UNAVAILABLE </li>";
      }
?>
```

Just use the if part only it will show the message, no need of else part

Comment: The reason for the conditional was to add the the_permalink if it was available but